# How to sort an array of objects with null properties

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, sorting, object

i have the following array

```
"data": {
    "risks": [
      {
        "id": "22",
        "name": true,
        "surname": 0.5,
        "age": 0.75,
        "heigth": 50,
        "num1": [],
        "num2": []
      },
      {
      "id": "55",
        "name": true,
        "surname": 0.5,
        "age": 0.75,
        "heigth": 50,
        "num1": [],
        "num2": []
      },
      {
          "id": "33",
        "name": true,
        "surname": 0.5,
        "age": 0.75,
        "heigth": 50,
        "num1": [1,2,3,4,5],
        "num2": [4,5,6,9]
      }
]}
```

is there a way to sort the array so the objects with empty num1 OR num2 to be last on the array ? i tried something like the following but it didnt work.

```
array.sort((x, y) => !!y.num1.length ==0- !!x.num1.length ==0|| !!y.num2.length ==0- !!x.num2.length ==0);
```

Comment: How do you want objects with non-empty num1/num2 arrays sorted?

Comment: You can do something like `array.sort((x, y) => ((x.num1.length+x.num2.length) > (y.num1.length+y.num2.length)) ? -1 : 1)` it will sort by the total cumulated length of num1 and num2

Comment: Please don't update questions to completely change the problem. If you have an additional issue, please open a new question separately to cover it.

Comment: @john ... what does the OP expect the example array to look like after sorting? What about edge cases? Does an array item always feature both `num` properties as array values or could a `num` property have a `null` value assigned or be entirely missing (`undefined`)? What about the expected sorting for the latter scenarios?

Answer (score 2):

You need to return an integer from the `sort()` method you implemented. Either `0` or `> 0` or `< 0` depending on the outcome of your comparison.

One of the simplest ways to check that at least `num1` or `num2` in any of your objects contains an entity is to sum their lengths and compare, something like this:

```js
const obj = {data:{risks:[{id:"22",name:!0,surname:.5,age:.75,heigth:50,num1:[],num2:[]},{id:"55",name:!0,surname:.5,age:.75,heigth:50,num1:[],num2:[]},{id:"33",name:!0,surname:.5,age:.75,heigth:50,num1:[1,2,3,4,5],num2:[4,5,6,9]}]}};

obj.data.risks = obj.data.risks.sort((a, b) => (b.num1.length + b.num2.length) - (a.num1.length + a.num2.length));
console.log(obj.data.risks);
```

Note that this approach is assuming that the arrays in the objects are always empty, never `null`.

Answer (score 0):

You could take the delta of the negated length for sorting empty arrays to bottom.

```js
const
    data = [{ id: "22", name: true, surname: 0.5, age: 0.75, heigth: 50, num1: [], num2: [] }, { id: "55", name: true, surname: 0.5, age: 0.75, heigth: 50, num1: [], num2: [] }, { id: "33", name: true, surname: 0.5, age: 0.75, heigth: 50, num1: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], num2: [4, 5, 6, 9] }, { id: "33", name: true, surname: 0.5, age: 0.75, heigth: 50, num1: [], num2: [4, 5, 6, 9] }, { id: "33", name: true, surname: 0.5, age: 0.75, heigth: 50, num1: [], num2: [4, 5, 6, 9] }];
    
data.sort((a, b) =>
    !a.num1.length - !b.num1.length ||
    !a.num2.length - !b.num2.length
);
    
console.log(data);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```